# how to set backgroundcolor of UIViewController in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to set backgroundcolor of UIViewController in iphone ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
myViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 21):

In IB, select the View in the view controller and click on the Background color selector or to do it in code:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's because UIColor ends in 'r' and that's the color that pops up when you press r again.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the much clearer way to write this code:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

This is the difference between dot notation (the previous answers) and method notation (my answer).

Answer (score 2):

For Swift:

```
myViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```